# How to map MapUniqueJsonKey for Json Claim Type

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, claims

I am using Identity Server 4 and UserProfileService to provide the custom claims for user.

There are two scenarios to cover:

1. Mvc application needs to get access to UserClaims via middleware
2. Other non .Net application needs to get access to UserClaims (Eg. Postman or React)

I tried two ways but still couldn't achieve both above requirements:

**Method 1**: Using `IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json`

In UserProfileService.cs, I added the claims like below:

```
var roles= new List<string>
{
    "products.read", "products.write", "products.delete"
};

claims.Add(new Claim("roles", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roles), IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json));
```

I generated the AccessToken and send the request to UserInfoEndpoint.  I got the following result successfully:

```
{
    "user_id": "950d44f1-d19e-412b-9fad-e0b59c11b2ec",
    ...
    "roles": [
        "products.read",
        "products.write",
        "products.delete"
    ],
    "sub": "950d44f1-d19e-412b-9fad-e0b59c11b2ec"
}
```

Then, I added this in the Mvc application\Startup.cs

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("roles", "roles", "json");
```

However, in my Mvc application, I got the error and it couldn't deserialize the roles array in the claim.

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Convert<T, U>(T token)
```

**Method 2**: Without Using `IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json`

If I removed IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json) when adding the claim types, it works in MVC app.  But it is showing as string in the postman instead of the Json object.  See below:

```
{
    "user_id": "950d44f1-d19e-412b-9fad-e0b59c11b2ec",    
    "permissions": "[\"products.read\",\"products.write\",\"products.delete\"]",
    "sub": "950d44f1-d19e-412b-9fad-e0b59c11b2ec"
}
```

I'm just wondering, is it by design or did I do something wrong?

Is there anyway to keep the claims in Json format and make Mvc claims mapping work for Array of strings in Claim?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post, but I stumbled over it as I have a similar problem. My `access_token` is OK, but roles are missing from the `.AspNetCore.Cookie` chunked cookie set. And that causes that as I have the correct roles when I call the API, I cannot use `Use.IsInRole()` in the web client.

And I fixed it by using `MapJsonKey()` instead of `MapUniqueJsonKey()`

In my case:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Role);
```